# Time-Delay estimation of transient signals using XCORR in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I have to compute the cross-correlation between two transient signals with non-zero mean. I read that the function `xcorr` in MATLAB works properly only with zero-mean inputs.

Since these signals represent transient phenomena, it doesn't make sense to me to subtract the mean value.

My objective is **to compute the time delay between the maximum values of the two signals**. The signals are not exactly correlated-similar, but I guess this is always the case.

If i try to compute the time delay using `xcorr`, I get close results to what I expect (i.e the time delay checked visually by checking where the maximum of the two signals are) only using the UNBIASED options.

Why is that? Does the unbiased routine subtract the mean values from both my signals?

Comment: What do you want to gain by using `xcorr` in contrast to simply ask for the maximum with `max` of both signals and then compare their indexes?

Comment: I thought this was a most precise way for computing the time delay, especially because in some other cases my signals are a little more nosiy and it's not straighforward to identify the maximum values. So I thougt that the cross-correlation was the best "tool" for doing this

Comment: If two signals are correlated and you want to calculate the general time delay, you are right. But that is not necessarily the same as the distance between the two tops, which is what you ask for in bold. This likely explains the difference you observe. So what do you really want?

Comment: My primary concern is to calculate the time delay of the maximum value between the two signals. I'd like to do this just when the signals have a similar shape, otherwise I would avoid using this method anyway. If the signals are too noisy I was hoping to achieve this using a cross-correlation, rather than registering the maximum value. Probably it's not the best way

Comment: Assuming you really mean maximum value, the solution is just using `[val, idx1] = max(ser1)` and similar for the other time-series and then compare the indexes. If it is not a maximum value but "just" a peak, you can use `findpeaks` instead of `max` with the same logic. If the signal is too noisy to find a maximum value/peak, what does the question then even mean?

Comment: Thanks, maybe using findpeaks can help me more than the cross-correlation.

Comment: Anyways, don't you think that if I use xcorr, I should obtain the same results? That is, the maximum of the correlation is at the time lag where the two maxima are overlapped?

Comment: `xcorr` compares the entire time series, so, e.g. if everything else but the tops fit better at som lag, then this will have the highest correlation.